# Does page curl segue auto-rotate?

Tags: ios, segue, autorotate

I have an app that has a 'partial curl' modal segue to a new UIViewcontroller but when I rotate the screen it remains in its original orientation. To fix it users would have to go back to the presenting UIViewcontroller and then rotate that one to change the one with the page curl which is all a bit of a hassle. It rotates with other types of segue such as 'Cover Vertical'.

Are UIViewcontrollers presented with a 'page curl' not supposed to auto-rotate?
Is there any way to make them rotate?

Thanks for any responses!

Comment: To me this is a bug. I asked the same question over a year ago (http://stackoverflow.com/q/11296960/1429262). I am surprised it still does not work!

Comment: ok, it might not be supported in iOS7 anyway so I may change it then

Answer (score 0):

I recently encountered this and believe it is a bug. Using the page curl animation prevented my orientation from changing. I had to switch the segue animation to be something other than page curl for the orientation to rotate.